# Adding a newline to my validation message ASP.Net MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a validation message and just below it I have a text field with some text.
When the validation message is hidden the text below the textfield is fine but when the validation message shows it's inline with the text below like in these pics. Is there any way to fix this so the validation message is on one line and the text is on a line below?

[image]

[image]

Here is the html code for the validation message

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastNameName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName, new { @id = "lastName", @class = "form-control" }) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <text>Your public profile only shows your first name.</text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the rendered HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lastNameName">Last Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">

    <input name="ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName" class="form-control input-validation-error" id="lastName" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="lastName-error" type="text" value="pareto" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$" data-val-regex="Hey, no funny symbol stuff"
      data-val-minlength-min="4" data-val-minlength="Minimum length is 4" data-val-maxlength-max="18" data-val-maxlength="Maximum length is 18">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName"><span id="lastName-error">Minimum length is 4</span></span>
    <text>Your public profile only shows your first name.</text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` inside a `<div>` (or style it)

Comment: nice! thanks! I have trouble with the little html things like this, well, and the big ones too

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the `bootstrap` class (`class="help-block"`) for `<text>Your public profile only shows your first name.</text>`like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lastNameName">Last Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">

    <input name="ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName" class="form-control input-validation-error" id="lastName" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="lastName-error" type="text" value="pareto" data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$" data-val-regex="Hey, no funny symbol stuff"
      data-val-minlength-min="4" data-val-minlength="Minimum length is 4" data-val-maxlength-max="18" data-val-maxlength="Maximum length is 18">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName"><span id="lastName-error">Minimum length is 4</span></span>

    <div class="help-block">Your public profile only shows your first name.</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[**Online output**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ali_soltani/L7mvdtco/)

For more information about Bootstrap class for validator elements see [this](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to wrap error text is using a `div` wrapper or a CSS class into `htmlAttributes` with `display: block` selector:

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    display: block;
}
```

**View (CSHTML)**

```
@* Using div *@
<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
<text>Your public profile only shows your first name.</text>

@* Using CSS class *@
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProfileGeneralViewModel.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger wrap" })
<text>Your public profile only shows your first name.</text>
```